# Synchronizing Series Group Colors for Charts in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart where I am trying to show a timeline of process logs per system. It is displaying all the logs correctly on the chart, giving a unique color to each log. I'm trying to see if I can color code the logs by specific attributes. Example: Each process log has a Cycle Type value. I'd like to have all logs with the same cycle type value to be the same color.

[image: Bar Chart]

It seems that the "Synchronize Groups in" property under the "Series Group Properties" is where I would put the Cycle Type value in, but the combobox for that property is empty, and if I hard code the cycle type value in, the report throws an error.

So right now I'm wondering what populates the "Synchronize Groups In" combobox for Series Groups?

[image: Series Group Properties]

I could potentially hard code the series color to set the color based on the Cycle Type values, but I'm looking for something more dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. Typically I would add a table, either a physical database table or a temporary one defined in your dataset query.

Essentially I would end up with an additional column containing my desired colour as a hex value but stored as a string, so the column might contain `#3D5070` as a string. I then use an expression as the series colour, something like `=Fields!myColourColumn.Value` . I'm typing this from memory so you *might* need to wrap this in a `FIRST()`.

I prefer this approach as you can have simple table containing either an ID, a  description (or both) and the colour, then you can join this in your dataset query and re-use it in other reports, knowing you will get a consistent theme.

You can also write a VB function to do the same kind of thing, but you have to plug that into every report and it's not quite as flexible as the database approach.

There are other method to such as this one in the SSRS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/specify-consistent-colors-across-multiple-shape-charts-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I was hoping you were going to explain how the `Synchronize Groups In` works.

Comment: I was going to but as I've never used it, I took the cowards way out and just pointed to the docs ! :) It seems that it only applies to shape charts and sparklines that are within a tablix control, not just a collection of charts that are in the report.